# Spinner/Progress Bar not visible on Android Lollipop - api 21+

Tags: android, android-progressbar

[image]

Left hand preview is Marshmallow, middle is API 16 and far right is API 21 i.e. Lollipop

Notice, on anything below 21, the progress bar is shown as expected, however on 21+ it not only isn't rendered in the XML preview, but also not in the final app. I have updated all build tools and libraries and targeting the latest API in my gradle build.

All code in project:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="@color/listview_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/listView"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Provide code & xml demonstrating how you're using the spinner.  I'm certain it does work on newer API versions, as I've used it myself on 5.1 and 6.0.

Comment: @user3137702 have added all code to post, fresh project, no code interacting with progress bar. Simple xml layout

Comment: After removing the missing refs (tool_bar & listview_divider), it's working fine for me.  It's not showing up in the preview (it is -- but invisible / no progress), but it's showing in the emulator correctly and on my physical device.

Comment: @user3137702 Hm, then i wonder what is corrupt? Any ideas where to begin? I just freshly downloaded API 24 (7.0) and it does not work with that either, along with new build tools and such so i'm not sure what to try in terms of uninstalling/re-installing

Comment: Well I would first just remove those two lines from your XML -- the layout include and the divider color -- and see if it works in the emulator, as that's the only difference (I think) between our projects.  Maybe you just typoed something in your layout or style files.

Comment: FYI on my end I simply opened android studio and created a new project with no activity.  After it was done, I created an empty activity through the project context menu and pasted in your XML.  Nothing else beyond removing those two lines I mentioned.